# Functions stop working after image is uploaded into canvas

Tags: javascript, html

So I upload an image file and draw it to canvas but this stops the cropping function on the page to not work.

The upload code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<input type='file' id="fileUpload" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID

var canvas  = el("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function readImage() {
if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
       var img = new Image();
       img.addEventListener("load", function() {
         context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
       });
       img.src = e.target.result;
    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
}

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

I am cropping images using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213413/canvas-cropping-images-in-different-shapes) solution.

Currently I have replaced the

```
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/houses1.jpg";
```

with the alternative upload script but this seems to stop the cropping script.

Are there any solutions to this?